# How to Use if conditions (or when ) for an attribute inside a template in xslt

Tags: xslt

HI All,

How to use the if condition for an attribute to print different value when its looped everytime.
I have an attribute called "AttributeName". This shall take different name when it is looped for each time (total 5 times).

I tried few things.. but it didnt work out. My Input XML will not have any data for this. All I have to do is to print different value each time when the loop goes till 5 times.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    </Solution>
    <Solution>
        <ID>22060000000000000000000002</ID>
        <Title>ABCD</Title>
        <Observations>
            <Observation>DEF</Observation>
        </Observations>
        <ProblemDescription> 1234</ProblemDescription>
        <ProblemCause>ADDD</ProblemCause>
        <RepairProcedures>
            <RepairProcedure>XYZ</RepairProcedure>
        </RepairProcedures>
        <ScenarioExplanation>
            <Scenario>JIJIJIJIJI</Scenario>
            <Scenario>SCENARIO1.</Scenario>
        </ScenarioExplanation>
        <DocumentReferences>
            <DocRef>NO DATA</DocRef>
        </DocumentReferences>
    </Solution>
</Solutions>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  

<xsl:stylesheet><xsl:template>  
            <xsl:element name="Tables">

            <!-- Tables code here -->

            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="Relationships">
                <xsl:for-each select="Solutions/Solution">
                    <xsl:if test="RepairProcedures/RepairProcedure!= ''  ">
                        <xsl:for-each select="RepairProcedures/RepairProcedure">
                            <xsl:variable name="vNumCols" select="5"/>
                            <xsl:element name="Relationship">
                                <xsl:for-each select="position() &lt; vNumCols">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Action"><xsl:value-of select="'Insert'"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="DestinationKey"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="RelationshipSpec"><xsl:value-of select="'TableName'"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="SourceKey"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="RelCommonKey"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="AttributeName">
                                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1"><xsl:value-of select="CPComments"/></xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="position() = 2"><xsl:value-of select="CPConflict"/></xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="AttributeValue"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am looping through repairprocedures/repairprocedure is to get the "RelationshipSpec" text.

Expected output

```
<Relationships>
<Relationship Action="Delete" DestinationKey="1" RelationshipSpec="XYZ" SourceKey="2" RelCommonKey="1_2" AttributeName="CPComments" AttributeValue=""/>  
<Relationship Action="Delete" DestinationKey="1" RelationshipSpec="XYZ" SourceKey="2" RelCommonKey="1_2" AttributeName="CPConflict" AttributeValue=""/>
<Relationship Action="Delete" DestinationKey="1" RelationshipSpec="XYZ" SourceKey="2" RelCommonKey="1_2" AttributeName="CPUserID" AttributeValue=""/>
<Relationship Action="Delete" DestinationKey="1" RelationshipSpec="XYZ" SourceKey="2" RelCommonKey="1_2" AttributeName="ProcessID" AttributeValue=""/>
<Relationship Action="Delete" DestinationKey="1" RelationshipSpec="XYZ" SourceKey="2" RelCommonKey="1_2" AttributeName="ProductId" AttributeValue=""/>         
</Relationships>
```

The only value changed in these 5 rows is "AttributeName". I am trying to print 5 rows for one relation with AttributeName being different.

Please help me in doing this.

I am using XSLT 1.0

Thank you,
Ramm

Comment: It would be easier for all if you could provide sample input (your xml sample does not contain any attribute at all) and your expected output for that input.

Comment: @qwerty : My input xml is just to print RepairProcedure Value.There will be no attributes. My o/p will have that value. I added the xslt and expectedoutput. but its displaing blank. I think formatting issues. I tried few times.. but not sure how the xslt to be formatted .. ;(

Comment: You use <xsl:for-each> too much. Try to use <xsl:apply-templates> instead of it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any relation between not well formed input sample and desired output. Please correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:attribute name="FirstAttribute">
        <xsl:value-of select="CPComments"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() = 2">
    <xsl:attribute name="SecondAttribute">
        <xsl:value-of select="CPConflict"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

work?

I would probably prefer `<xsl:choose>`, but it's not like it would have been shorter anyway.

Comment: Hi Jan. this adds an extra attribute in the same row. But, I need this attribute "CPConflict" to be displayed in the second row rather in the first.